# XV6 signals clash with macOS signals

Tags: xcode, macos, signals, macos-big-sur, xv6

I'm trying to implement signals support on [XV6-riscv](https://github.com/mit-pdos/xv6-riscv) version
And in order to d so I defined a `sigaction struct` and some signals macros like `SIG_IGN`.
The problem is that when I compile it using `make clean qemu` I got the following errors:

```
In file included from mkfs/mkfs.c:9:
./kernel/types.h:12:8: error: redefinition of 'sigaction'
struct sigaction {
       ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/signal.h:286:9: note: previous definition is here
struct  sigaction {
        ^
In file included from mkfs/mkfs.c:9:
./kernel/types.h:13:12: error: expected ')'
    void (*sa_handler) (int);
           ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/signal.h:295:38: note: expanded from macro 'sa_handler'
#define sa_handler      __sigaction_u.__sa_handler
                                     ^
./kernel/types.h:13:10: note: to match this '('
    void (*sa_handler) (int);
         ^
In file included from mkfs/mkfs.c:12:
./kernel/param.h:14:9: error: 'SIG_DFL' macro redefined [-Werror,-Wmacro-redefined]
#define SIG_DFL      0       // default signal handling
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/signal.h:131:9: note: previous definition is here
#define SIG_DFL         (void (*)(int))0
        ^
In file included from mkfs/mkfs.c:12:
./kernel/param.h:15:9: error: 'SIG_IGN' macro redefined [-Werror,-Wmacro-redefined]
#define SIG_IGN      1       // ignore signal
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/signal.h:132:9: note: previous definition is here
#define SIG_IGN         (void (*)(int))1
        ^
4 errors generated.
make: *** [mkfs/mkfs] Error 1
```

From what I understand sys the new definitions I made already exist in the macOS signal.h file and I do not understand why the compiler even checking this file? since it is in no way relevant for the XV6 and how can I fix this?
Any help would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution if anyone will encounter the same problem in the future:

`mkfs/mkfs.c` is not a part of xv6. it's just a utility to build xv6. but `kernel/types.h` is included in `mkfs/mkfs.c`.
and this `mkfs/mkfs.c` is compiled like a regular program ([see here](https://github.com/mit-pdos/xv6-riscv/blob/077323a8f0b3440fcc3d082096a2d83fe5461d70/Makefile#L109)). so it redefines struct sigaction which is previously defined in macOS `signal.h`

****The solution** is not to use `kernel/types.h` for the implementation**.

Just create some new header files instead and leave `kernel/types.h` in its original state unchanged.